# CSS placement, image beside a legend

Tags: html, css

Hello I am currently trying to place a legend beside one of my images and I am having trouble with the placement.

I would like to bring the legend up to either the left or the right of the image. This is my current code:

```css
.my-legend .legend-title {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
  font-size: 80%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.my-legend .legend-source {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #999;
  clear: both;
}

.my-legend a {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<img src="images/homeview.png" height="500">
<p><i>*Color coded home view example</i></p>
<hr>
<div class='my-legend'>
  <div class='legend-scale'>
    <ul class='legend-labels'>
      <li><span style='background:#F7F7F7;'></span>Available</li>
      <li><span style='background:#FFA500;'></span>Parked & Loaded</li>
      <li><span style='background:#2E8B57;'></span>Parked & Unloaded</li>
      <li><span style='background:#41B1E1;'></span>Docked</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything like float or display ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I have messed around with the floats but it didn't get me anywhere

Comment: with the float, you can set the first element floatting `img {float:left;}`, but you need enough room to see them stand side by side and vertical-alignement will not be avalaible  . Display:flex/grid or even tablewill be more efficient, you need at least 2 wrappers , one for img and the other one for the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, these are a few method tha could be used :

- basic example with floatting the first `img` *(what you obviously tried. It requires a `min-width` to avoid wrapping)* :

```css
.my-legend .legend-title {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
  font-size: 80%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.my-legend .legend-source {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #999;
  clear: both;
}

.my-legend a {
  color: #777;
}
img {float:left;}
body {min-width:600px;
```

```html
<img src="images/homeview.png" height="500">
<p><i>*Color coded home view example</i></p>
<hr>
<div class='my-legend'>
  <div class='legend-scale'>
    <ul class='legend-labels'>
      <li><span style='background:#F7F7F7;'></span>Available</li>
      <li><span style='background:#FFA500;'></span>Parked & Loaded</li>
      <li><span style='background:#2E8B57;'></span>Parked & Unloaded</li>
      <li><span style='background:#41B1E1;'></span>Docked</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

- wrappers and `display:table-cell` to allow `vertical-alignment` *(for older browsers)*

```css
.my-legend .legend-title {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
  font-size: 80%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.my-legend .legend-source {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #999;
  clear: both;
}

.my-legend a {
  color: #777;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  /* avalaible option */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-cell"><img src="images/homeview.png" height="500"></div>
<div class="table-cell">
  <p><i>*Color coded home view example</i></p>
  <hr>
  <div class='my-legend'>
    <div class='legend-scale'>
      <ul class='legend-labels'>
        <li><span style='background:#F7F7F7;'></span>Available</li>
        <li><span style='background:#FFA500;'></span>Parked & Loaded</li>
        <li><span style='background:#2E8B57;'></span>Parked & Unloaded</li>
        <li><span style='background:#41B1E1;'></span>Docked</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

- wrappers and `flex` *(for a partial layout):*

```css
.my-legend .legend-title {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
  font-size: 80%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.my-legend .legend-source {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #999;
  clear: both;
}

.my-legend a {
  color: #777;
}

.flex-parent{
  display:flex;
  /* avalaible option */
  align-items:center;
 /* also : justify-content: center or else */
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
<div class="flex-child"><img src="images/homeview.png" height="500"></div>
<div class="flex-child">
  <p><i>*Color coded home view example</i></p>
  <hr>
  <div class='my-legend'>
    <div class='legend-scale'>
      <ul class='legend-labels'>
        <li><span style='background:#F7F7F7;'></span>Available</li>
        <li><span style='background:#FFA500;'></span>Parked & Loaded</li>
        <li><span style='background:#2E8B57;'></span>Parked & Unloaded</li>
        <li><span style='background:#41B1E1;'></span>Docked</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

- wrappers with `grid` *(useful for main layout)*

```css
.my-legend .legend-title {
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
  font-size: 80%;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.my-legend .legend-source {
  font-size: 70%;
  color: #999;
  clear: both;
}

.my-legend a {
  color: #777;
}

.grid-parent{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2,auto);
  /* avalaible option */
  align-items:center;
 /* also : justify-content: center or else */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-parent">
<div class="grid-child"><img src="images/homeview.png" height="500"></div>
<div class="grid-child">
  <p><i>*Color coded home view example</i></p>
  <hr>
  <div class='my-legend'>
    <div class='legend-scale'>
      <ul class='legend-labels'>
        <li><span style='background:#F7F7F7;'></span>Available</li>
        <li><span style='background:#FFA500;'></span>Parked & Loaded</li>
        <li><span style='background:#2E8B57;'></span>Parked & Unloaded</li>
        <li><span style='background:#41B1E1;'></span>Docked</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

`inline-block` or `position` coud also work but are tricky for this purpose and not made for this however.

---

**extra** , html5 comes with `figure` and `figcaption`, it seems a typical use here

```
<figure>
 <img src="theImg.pct">
 <figcaption>
   text that belongs to theImg 
 </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficent ?

```css
.my-legend .legend-title {
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

.my-legend .legend-scale ul li {
    font-size: 80%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.my-legend ul.legend-labels li span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 26px;
    width: 40px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}

.my-legend .legend-source {
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #999;
    clear: both;
}

.my-legend a {
    color: #777;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="https://qomra.pro/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/placeholder-1.png" width="200">
    <div>
        <p><i>*Color coded home view example</i></p>
        <hr>
        <div class='my-legend'>
            <div class='legend-scale'>
                <ul class='legend-labels'>
                    <li><span style='background:#F7F7F7;'></span>Available</li>
                    <li><span style='background:#FFA500;'></span>Parked & Loaded</li>
                    <li><span style='background:#2E8B57;'></span>Parked & Unloaded</li>
                    <li><span style='background:#41B1E1;'></span>Docked</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is, but can you explain what you changed? I see you added a container. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I added a container, and added styling to it `display: flex;`. Then I added the contents rather than the image in another container. `display: flex;` made the image and the second container appear in a row instead of a column.

Comment: using this CSS throws the rest of the page off unfortuanly as seen here: https://prnt.sc/rhc95n and its suppose to look like this: https://prnt.sc/rhc9n3

Comment: Yes, how can I send it to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209724/discussion-between-jake-pavek-and-seif-el-din-sweilam).